# $k$-algebra endomorphisms of $k^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, and consider the $k$-algebra $k^2$ with basis $e_1=(1,0), e_2=(0,1)$. I'm interested in finding all $k$-algebra homomorphisms $k^2 \to k^2$.

First, we note that such a homomorphism, call it $f$, is $k$-linear, and hence determined by its values on the basis elements. Let $f(e_i)=\sum_j a_j e_j$. We need to specify which of the $a_j$ yield a $k$-algebra homomorphism.

We have $f(e_1)+f(e_2)=f(e_1+e_2)=f(1)=1$ and $f(e_1)f(e_2)=f(e_1e_2)=f(0)=0$, as well as $f(e_i)^2= f(e_i^2)= f(e_i)$. Hence the images $f(e_1)$ and $f(e_2)$ are orthogonal idempotents.

I'm having trouble using this fact to say something interesting about the $a_j$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your algebra has dimension two. Therefore write it down like this:
$f(e_1)=ae_1+be_2$ and $f(e_2)=ce_1+de_2$. Substitute this into your sum and product formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not any harder to consider more generally $k$-algebra homomorphisms $f : k^n \to k^m$. The argument goes like this: writing $e_1, \dots e_n$ for the standard basis of $k^n$, we know that $\{ e_i \}$ are orthogonal idempotents in $k^n$ summing to $1$, so $\{ f(e_i) \}$ are $n$ orthogonal idempotents in $k^m$ summing to $1$. Conversely given such a collection of orthogonal idempotents the corresponding $f$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism. So it remains to classify these.

The idempotents in $k^m$ are exactly the vectors with entries either $0$ or $1$, so they can be thought of as characteristic functions of subsets of $[m] = \{ 1, 2, \dots m \}$. They are orthogonal iff they are disjoint subsets, and they sum to $1$ iff their union is $[m]$. What this tells us is that the subsets form a partition of $[m]$ into $n$ subsets, so every $i \in [m]$ is in the support of a unique $f(e_j), j \in [n]$. This defines a function $g : [m] \to [n]$ such that $f$ is the pullback of $g$ (and the partition is given by the fibers of $g$), and all $f$ arise uniquely in this way.

The conclusion is that the category of $k$-algebras of the form $k^n$ is contravariantly equivalent to the category of finite sets, with the equivalence given by sending a map $g : X \to Y$ of finite sets to the pullback map $g^{\ast} : k^Y \to k^X$. This is perhaps the simplest "algebra to geometry" correspondence of the sort studied in algebraic geometry.

In particular, functions $k^2 \to k^2$ correspond to functions $[2] \to [2]$ from a $2$-element set to itself, in the opposite direction, and there are exactly four of these: the identity, the transposition, the constant function with constant value $1$, and the constant function with constant value $2$. These correspond to the identity, the transposition $(x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$, the pullback $(x, y) \mapsto (x, x)$, and the pullback $(x, y) \mapsto (y, y)$ respectively.

$k$ can be replaced with any [connected ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_ring) here.

Comment: That's the same question. I didn't assume any relationship between $m$ and $n$; they're arbitrary non-negative integers here.